# Returning all items to IEnumerable with iteration

Tags: c#, file

I have a binary file with fixed record length of 100 and want to read all records in file with this code:

```
    public IEnumerable<Book> GetAll()
    {
        Book book;
        using (Stream st = File.Open(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/") + "library.majid", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read))
        {
            long len = st.Length;
            using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(st))
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < len / 100; i++)
                {
                    st.Position = i * 100;
                    if (!reader.ReadBoolean())
                        yield return null;
                    book = new Book()
                    {
                        Id = reader.ReadInt32(),
                        Name = reader.ReadString(),
                        Dewey = reader.ReadString()
                    };
                    try
                    {
                        book.Subject = reader.ReadString();
                        book.RegDate = reader.ReadInt32();
                        book.PubDate = reader.ReadInt32();
                    }
                    catch (EndOfStreamException) { } 
                    yield return book;
                }

            }
        }

    }
 public static DataTable ListBooks(this IEnumerable<classes.Book> objs)
    { 

        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        table.Columns.Add("id",typeof(int));
        table.Columns.Add("name",typeof(String));
        table.Columns.Add("dewey", typeof(String));
        table.Columns.Add("subject", typeof(String));
        table.Columns.Add("reg");
        table.Columns.Add("pub");
        var values = new object[6];
        if (objs != null)
            foreach (classes.Book item in objs)
            {
                values[0] = item.Id;
                values[1] = item.Name;
                values[2] = item.Dewey;
                values[3] = item.Subject;
                values[4] = ((DateTime)IntToDateTime(item.RegDate)).ToLongDateString();
                if (item.PubDate != null)
                    values[5] = IntToDateTime(item.PubDate);
                else
                    values[5] = "";
                table.Rows.Add(values);
            }
        return table;
    }
```

when I want to use use the results with `ListBooks(GetAll())`I see this error in first line of `foreach`:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from anything else, in various places in your code you `yield return null`. That means `item` will be null within your loop (assuming you *actually* call `getAll()`). That in turn means that fetching `item.Id` will throw an exception.

I suspect that each of your `yield return null`; statements should either be `continue;` or `yield break;`. (I'd also urge you not to silently swallow exceptions, and to always use braces even for single-statement `if` bodies.)